# jQueryMobile Not applying high resolution icons on retina display

Tags: web-applications, jquery-mobile, icons, resolution, retina-display

I'm building a web app using jQueryMobile (primarily) - exclusively for the iPhone 4s, and I'm having the following issue:

The icons that are included with jQueryMobile are not displaying properly (not displaying in High Resolution) on an iPhone 4s with retina display.  All the custom icons I've used do display properly in high resolution format, but the default icons are not loading in high-res.

I've verified that this is not just my imagination, as I can see that the file that is getting loaded is "icons-18-white.png" rather than "icons-36-white.png".

I'm not using media queries as this is device specific, and doesn't need them.

Is there something I'm missing?  Or any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what code would be helpful.  There are 8 pages - I can show the head if you think that would be helpful.  What do you think?

Comment: Whatever kind soul - nearly 5 months after I posted this - decided it would be useful to downvote it without comment, I thank you for your useful contribution.  May you have continued success in dispensing your unmatched wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check this out? This is just something I just found after doing a quick Google search.

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/17/designing-for-iphone-4-retina-display-techniques-and-workflow/